# Undefined control sequence for beta symbol list

Tags: math-mode, symbols, math-operators

I am new to Latex, please help me!

I would like to give a beta symbol with a sequence of values as below.

```
\boldsymbol{\beta} = (\beta_1,\beta_2,\dotsc,\beta_n)
```

output looks promising.

```
β = (β1, β2, , βn) (1)
```

But I get an error like

```
Undefined control sequence.
l.77 \boldsymbol
                {\beta} = (\beta_1,\beta_2,\dotsc,\beta_n)
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed.
```

Please help me to fix this.

Comment: You need to load the `amsmath` package.

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) always provide full minimal examples so we do not have to guess your preamble (3) load time the `bm` package and use `\bm` to mark the bold symbols

Comment: @Mico I've imported it but it doesn't work...

Comment: @Mico need to import usepackage bm also `\usepackage{amsmath} % for \boldsymbol macro
\usepackage{bm}      % for \bm macro`

Comment: @CharlieParker - Please re-read the original posting and then my comment. The original posting contained a `\boldsymbol` directive -- which "did not work" -- and, importantly, it did *not* contain a `\bm` directive. The only non-bizarre way my comment can be construed is that it addresses the OP's complaint by pointing out that it's necessary to load the `amsmath` package in order to get to use the `\boldsymbol` directive. Since there was no `\bm` directive in the OP's code, I saw no need to further point out that it would be necessary to load the `bm` package in order to activate `\bm`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To use `\boldsymbol` (in math mode, of course), you need to load the [amsmath](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) package.

Alternatively, load the [bm](http://ctan.org/pkg/bm) ("bold math") package and write `\bm{\beta}` (again in math mode, of course).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for \boldsymbol macro
\usepackage{bm}      % for \bm macro
\begin{document}
$\boldsymbol{\beta} = (\beta_1,\beta_2,\dots,\beta_n)$

$\bm{\beta} = (\beta_1,\beta_2,\dots,\beta_n)$
\end{document}
```

Comment: The manual of `amsbsy` (loaded by `amsmath` and providing `\boldsymbol`) recommends using `\bm` instead of `\boldsymbol`.

Comment: @egreg - The manual of the `amsmath` package provides the same recommendation, while narrowing it a bit, by stating that the `bm` should be loaded and `\bm` be used if a user doesn't require the (many!) other facilities of the `amsmath` package. Of course, if `bm` is loaded *after* `amsmath`, the instruction `\let\boldsymbol\bm` is executed, and bm's bolding method is used whenever `\boldsymbol` is typed (as is the case in my MWE...).

Comment: I've imported it but it doesn't work...

Comment: @CharlieParker - Please clarify your comment. In particular, what does the first instance of "it" refer to?